# ember.js #each order by property

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have an array of `Ember.Object`s which is displayed by Handlebars `{{#each}}` helper which I want to be sorted by an property of those objects everytime the array changes.

So something like this:

```
var arr = [
    Ember.Objects.create({
        position:0,
        label:"foo"
    }),
    Ember.Objects.create({
        position:1,
        label:"bar"
    }),
];
```

And the handlebar

```
{{#each arr}}
    <div class="label">{{label}}</div>
{{/each}}
```

So if I update the positions and the `bar` object becomes first, I want the view to be updated. Can I depend the `{{#each}}` Helper on an property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use an `ArrayController` proxy on your data, and set the `sortProperties` attribute. Then, use the controller as the `each` data source.

Sample @ http://jsfiddle.net/MikeAski/Epjqp/

Using the controller as the data source provides an arranged content. Take care not to use directly the controller's `content`, as it is the raw source data...