# Ember.js CollectionView order

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have an `ArrayController` which is periodically updated. It has a `sorted` computed property which keeps things in order. I'm trying to use a `CollectionView` with it's `content` property bound to the `sorted` property, but it's not rendering them in the correct order. [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/URFr8/1/)

I've obviously made the false assumption that order is maintained between the `content` and `childViews` property. What is the correct way to do this?

**Handlebars**:

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="item">
    id {{view.content.id}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <ul>
     {{collection
        contentBinding="App.itemController.sorted"
        itemViewClass="App.ItemView"
    }} 
    </ul>        
</script>
```

**JavaScript**:

```js
​App = Ember.Application.create({
    ready: function(){

        // add a new object with a random id
        // every second
        setInterval(function(){

            var id = Math.round(Math.random() * 100),
                obj = Em.Object.create({ id: id });
            App.itemController.pushObject(obj);

        }, 1000);

    }
});

// Collection Item View
App.ItemView = Em.View.extend({
    tagName: "li",
    templateName: "item"
});

App.itemController = Em.ArrayController.create({

    // random order
    content: Em.A([
        Em.Object.create({ id: 5 }),
        Em.Object.create({ id: 3 }),
        Em.Object.create({ id: 10 }),
        Em.Object.create({ id: 6 }),
        Em.Object.create({ id: 1 }),
        Em.Object.create({ id: 2 }),
        Em.Object.create({ id: 100 }),
    ]),

    // filtered content
    sorted: function(){
        return this.get('content').sort(function(a,b){
            return a.get('id') - b.get('id');
        });
    }.property("@each")

});
```

​

Comment: where is pangratz when we need him?

Comment: For once, we do not need pangratz here ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the sake of completeness to @sly7_7's correct answer, here is a version with `CollectionView`, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/ctPAA/.

**Handlebars**:

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{collection
        tagName="ul"
        contentBinding="App.itemController"
        itemViewClass="App.ItemView" }} 
</script>
```

**JavaScript**:

```js
App.itemController = Em.ArrayController.create({

    sortProperties: 'id'.w(),

    // random order
    content: Em.A([
        ...
    ])

});
```

Comment: When @tomdale created the sortable mixin, he was beside me, and tell me to not use the arrangedContent. But here, your example works perfectly, and without the duplicate issue. I think ilia should accept this one... grrrr Clemens, you're always better ;)

Comment: I've added the note about the bug and I will update the answer when it has been fixed. I wouldn't say better, your answer works too :) I didn't want to compete ;)

Comment: Would there be a way to add additional filtering to this?

Comment: @iliacholy At work we did this kind of thing by defining an ad hoc filtering mixin. I think they plan to implement this built-in in ember.
Clemens, no problem, I've learnt one more thing today. I like this kind of shared experience :), I was not talking about competition :)

Answer (score 5):

Inspired by this answer: [ember.js #each order by property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205013/ember-js-each-order-by-property)

I use the sorting properties of ArrayController: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-runtime/lib/mixins/sortable.js

I don't use CollectionView, but a simple #each, and call to addObject instead of pushObject

**template**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="item">
    id {{view.content.id}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
    <ul>
     {{#each item in App.itemController}}
        {{view App.ItemView contentBinding="item"}}
     {{/each}} 
    <li>        
</script>
```

**javascript**

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
  ready: function() {

    // add a new object with a random id
    // every second
    setInterval(function(){
        var id = Math.round(Math.random() * 100),
            obj = Em.Object.create({ id: id });
        // should call addObject, because pushObject does not sort the inserted item
        //App.itemController.pushObject(obj); 
        App.itemController.addObject(obj);
    }, 1000);
  }       
});

// Collection Item View
App.ItemView = Em.View.extend({
  tagName: "li",
  templateName: "item"
});

App.itemController = Em.ArrayController.create({
  sortProperties: ['id'],
  // random order
  content: Em.A([
    Em.Object.create({ id: 5 }),
    Em.Object.create({ id: 3 }),
    Em.Object.create({ id: 10 }),
    Em.Object.create({ id: 6 }),
    Em.Object.create({ id: 1 }),
    Em.Object.create({ id: 2 }),
    Em.Object.create({ id: 100 }),
  ]),
});
App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'application'
});
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend();
App.Router = Ember.Router.extend({root: Em.Route.extend()});
App.initialize();​
```

The jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Sly7/LJAYk/

Comment: hmm, I was hoping this wouldn't be the only option due to the duplicate views issue. https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/729

Comment: I guess that won't be an issue after the `each` helper accepts an `itemViewClass`

Comment: I was not aware of thi bug, I should be more careful about emberjs issues list... anyway, the answer given by @pangratz works around this

Comment: In my particular case this is what I used because I required additional filtering of my content before sorting. But I didn't specify that in the question and pangratz's answer is a better answer to the general question.

Comment: Yep :), it's fair, no problem at all

Comment: I've updated my answer against ember-latest. Some bugs have been corrected in the sortableMixin, but the drawback is you have to fully initialize the application.