# Is there an informative article about how to use the SortableMixin?

Tags: ember.js

At the moment I'm using JavaScript's native `sort()` method to do my sorting in Ember, but in reality I know I should be using Ember's own sorting, but unfortunately I have absolutely no idea how to use it.

I don't want to waste people's time in explaining it for me (unless you're a masochist), but if anybody knows of a fabulous article on how to sort a collection of models in EmberJS, then it would be more than appreciated!

At the moment I have something like the following, where I'm just about the implement the sorting using the native sort again, but I stopped myself there because I want to learn the proper way.

```
SortOption: Ember.View.extend(
{
    template:   Ember.Handlebars.compile('<li><a href="javascript:void(0);">{{ option }}</a></li>'),
    option:     null,

    click: function()
    {
        var rootView    = this.nearestWithProperty('people');
        var sortBy      = this.get('option');

        var sorted = rootView.get('people').orderBy('formalName');
        rootView.set('people', sorted)
    }
})
```

Comment: I tried the `orderBy` method from looking at the `SortableMixin`, but Firebug tells me that there's no such method.

Comment: Perhaps my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11352646/ember-js-collectionview-order/11353305#11353305 could help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This pull request](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/1255/files) is for updated documentation regarding SortableMixin.

```
Ember.SortableMixin provides a standard interface for array proxies
to specify a sort order and maintain this sorting when objects are added,
removed, or updated without changing the implicit order of their underlying
content array:
  songs = [ 
   {trackNumber: 4, title: 'Ob-La-Di, Ob-La-Da'},
   {trackNumber: 2, title: 'Back in the U.S.S.R.'},
   {trackNumber: 3, title: 'Glass Onion'},
  ];  

  songsController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
  content: songs,
  sortProperties: ['trackNumber']

 });

 songsController.get('firstObject'); // {trackNumber: 2, title: 'Back in the U.S.S.R.'}
 songsController.addObject({trackNumber: 1, title: 'Dear Prudence'});
 songsController.get('firstObject'); // {trackNumber: 1, title: 'Dear Prudence'}
```

Sortable Mixin is now included in the ArrayController as of 0.9.8 release (I believe). All you need to do is define a sortProperties array on your controller and use the `arrangedContent` property in your views. [Here is an explanation from Ivan.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11405883/1406961)