# Refreshing a containerView on sort

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to sort a containerView after it's already been displayed. However, since the length of the array does not change but only the order, the view is not refreshed. Is there a best practice on how to force the view to rerender?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11352646/ember-js-collectionview-order and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205013/ember-js-each-order-by-property should be fine for you :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you grab the latest build off of Embers GitHub page here: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/downloads it includes the Ember.ArrayController, which in turn uses the Ember.SortableMixin.

You define your controller like so:

```
HS.BlogPostsListController = Em.ArrayController.create({
    content: [],
    sortAscending: false,
    sortProperties: ['postDate'],
    //the rest of your controller definition...
}
```

Then you bind your view your controller's arrangedContent property like so:

```
{{#view MyApp.view contentBinding="HS.BlogPostListController.arrangedContent" ...}}
```

This will keep your view updated when the sorting changes (when you change your sortAscending or sortProperties properties).

If you do not want to pull the latest build, you should have a look at the SortableMixin source code and see if you can incorporate it in your own app: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-runtime/lib/mixins/sortable.js

EDIT: You can see the HS.BlogPostListController in action at GitHub Here: https://github.com/joachimhs/haagen-software.no/blob/master/app/controllers.js